# Flipping the emulator does not change the layout to the one present in layout-land

Tags: android, layout, orientation, landscape

my activity.xml :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:text="@string/first_last1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="86dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/first_last1"
        android:src="@drawable/johnvonneumann" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/about_scientist1" 
        android:textSize="16sp"/>

    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

my land\activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView21"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:text="@string/first_last2" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView21"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView21"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/first_last2"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/bruceschneier" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView21"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView21" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:text="@string/about_scientist2" 
        android:textSize="16sp"/>

    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

manifest file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="edu.assignment.scientists"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="edu.assignment.scientists.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

main_activity.java

```
package edu.assignment.scientists;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

When i flip the emulator using ctrl-F11, the orientation changes but the layout does not.
it still points to the layout mode only.
Please help.

Comment: try to delete this line in the Mainfest `  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"`

Comment: I tried this but does not help.

Comment: Can you confirm where your landscape xml is stored? In the folder res/land, res/layout/land or res/layout-land ?  It should be in the last one.

Comment: It is inside res/layout-land only.

Comment: coursera student don't waste your time, it is a bug in the emulator and google will not fix it :( https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13189

Comment: I got it working. I cleaned up the worksapce and started the eclipse. Thanks all!

Comment: @user1642882 I cleaned up my workspace and started my computer not eclipse and didn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  As Amir Ismail said, there is a bug in the 4.4 emulator.  I downloaded the 4.3 emulator and ran the exact same code and it worked perfectly.